# MongoDB : How to perform sharding without replication?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to accomplish sharding within 2 machines with config server, router, 1 shard in machine A and another shard in machine B. I am finding it hard to do this as I am a beginner and also can't find much documentation/ tutorials online. I have started a two mongod instances one as config server and another as shard, but clueless on how to proceed.

Below is the sharding configuration in two of my mongod (config and shard ) conf files:

Config server:

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr
```

Shard:

```
sharding:
  clusterRole : shardsvr
```

As per the documentation , the next step is to execute the command rs.initiate(), but I don't require replication. I still tried to execute just in case and received below error:

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
        "code" : 76,
        "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

Is it mandatory to have replication while sharding? How to do sharding without replication within 2 machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible, see [sharding Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#sharding-options):

> Note
>
> Setting `sharding.clusterRole` requires the mongod instance to be
> running with replication. To deploy the instance as a replica set
> member, use the `replSetName` setting and specify the name of the
> replica set.

But you can have a replica set with just one member, that's no problem.
The replica set will have only the primary, should work.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Unless my memory fails me, it used to be possible to have standalone mongod instances as shard servers.

Comment: Thanks. I just converted the standalone config server into a replica set. Can you guide me through any blogs/sites on sharding using one member replica sets?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ - should have examples for all cases.